# Issues with Sonata Admin Bundle Logo

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

This is a weird problem I am facing. The Sonata admin bundle logo and the title are displayed on 2 different lines..

[image: My Dashboard]

The following are the contents of my config file.

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

sonata_admin:
    title:      MyTitle
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

try your own logo

```
sonata_admin:
    title:      MyTitle
    title_logo: /bundles/yourbundle/images/logo.png
```